# how to read all the rows only from first column from excel using selenium java

Tags: java

[image: here is how the data looks like]

How to read all the rows from column "A" from excel. The excel has no headers vales, so i gave "A"

```
@Then("Verify logs for enf \"([^\"]*)\" from the \"([^\"]*)\" sheet$")
public void verifyLogs(String EnfID, String FileName) throws Exception {
Sheet sheet = getFilename(FileName);
int colIndex=-1;
String[] readFirstColumn= new String[] {"A"};
Iterator<Row> rowIt = sheet.rowIterator();
While(rowIt.hadNext()){
XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rowIt.next();
for (int a = 0; a < columnsToRead.length; a++) {
 //get column data
}
}

 public Sheet getFilename(String FileName) throws Exception {
    String filePath = "C://Filepath//";
    File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + FileName);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Logs");
    return sheet;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in XLSX file like this:

[image]

Code:

```
package apachePoi;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Tummalsr {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\data.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        XSSFCell firstColumnCell = null;
        int firstColumnRowCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++) {
            try {
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                firstColumnCell = row.getCell(0);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) {
                System.out.println("Cell is null at index: " + i);
            }
            if (firstColumnCell != null) {
                if (firstColumnCell.getStringCellValue().length() > 0) {
                    firstColumnRowCount = i;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= firstColumnRowCount; j++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(j);
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
        workbook.close();
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
Cell is null at index: 5
data1
data2
data3
data4
```

My maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: hi @pburgr . thanks for the ans . but my excel has two/three columns (attached screenshot of the excel) and when i use .getPhysicalNumberOfRows() it is taking the max number of rows in next column as well .

Comment: I've updated my answer. Should be fine now.